# How do i make a plot of a csv file which has pcap data in it like ip addresses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I converted a pcap file to csv and now want to use matplotlib or seaborn to plot let's say the Source ip and Destination ip address columns in python. How would I do that?

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
x = dataframe.Source
y = dataframe.Destination
```

how would I make a nice plot of the above code? and X and y have columns filled with ip addresses
thanks in advance!

Comment: What about a network graph? With nodes are your IP addresses and edges whether they appear in your dataframe as source & destination. Example here https://plot.ly/python/network-graphs/

Comment: How many distinct (x, y) do you have?

Comment: x has 35-50 ip addresses in column so does y

Comment: can anyone help me plot these 2 columns of ip addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a network visualisation suits your needs.

First, I define a toy dataframe

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["IP112", "IP2"],
                   ["IP11", "IP2"],
                   ["IP13", "IP2"],
                   ["IP12", "IP24"],
                   ["IP111", "IP24"],
                   ["IP14", "IP205"],
                   ["IP12", "IP2"],
                   ["IP13", "IP205"]], columns=["Source", "Destination"])
```

Now, using famous library `networkx` for such visualisations:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(df.Source.unique())  # add 'Source' nodes
G.add_nodes_from(df.Destination.unique())  # add 'Destination' nodes
G.add_edges_from(df.values)  # add all edges
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Renders:

[image]